# Lollipop make statusbar transparent on content frame of navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

i am trying to set status bar transparent on my content frame inside navigation drawer. I create the app using the template contain on android studio. I need make status bar transparent when navigation drawer is not open so my toolbar back ground is draw behind it.

This one:
[This One What I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H12V7.png)

Not this one, because it already transparent:
[Not this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vlp7m.png)

Answer (score 0):

I actually had an issue related to this due to some custom rendering with parallax effects... Anyway, you can just set the status bar background color in `onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)` and then set it back to transparent when opening the drawer:

```
public class WindowHelper {

    public static void setColoredStatusBar(Activity activity){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            Window window = activity.getWindow();
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.secondary_color));
        }
    }

    public static void setTranslucentStatusBar(Activity activity){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            Window window = activity.getWindow();
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }
    }
}
```

So for you it'd something like:

```
@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
    WindowHelper.setColoredStatusBar(activity);
}
```

Comment: Maybe its miss understanding. i dont wanna make the status bar colored when open. image on the "this one" the satus bar is in different color with the toolbar, all i want to do is to make status bar transparent so the color of my toolbar is shown behind it statusbar and the statusbar get same draw

Comment: The status bar when the NavigationDrawer is open is already transparent. If you look at the far right side, you can see your content view still has the same bar behind it. The effect you're seeing is that your NavigationDrawer content actually rests behind the transparent status bar, because it's view has the fitsSystemWindows="true" property. If you remove that attribute from both your content view and your NavigationDrawer, it will effectively place all content below the status bar.